# ORACLE SQL:Get all integers between two numbers

Tags: sql, oracle, numbers

Is there any way to select the numbers (integers) that are included between two numbers with SQL in Oracle; I don't want to create PL/SQL procedure or function.

For example I need to get the numbers between 3 and 10. The result will be the values 3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10.

Thx.

Answer (score 63):

This trick with Oracle's DUAL table also works:

```
SQL> select n from
  2  ( select rownum n from dual connect by level <= 10)
  3  where n >= 3;

         N
----------
         3
         4
         5
         6
         7
         8
         9
        10
```

Comment: best thing about this approach is in Oracle 10g and later, this requires no block reads :)

Comment: Nice and simple, love it! 
I used this to find all missing values within a range: 
`select n from
( select rownum n from dual connect by level <= 999)
where (select count(*) from table where index = n) = 0;`

Comment: I use this one all the time. Typically, to create a result set with empty rows for known good values that need to be tabulated (count etc.) but do not appear in the database records (outer join...).

Answer (score 5):

The *first* thing I do when I create a new database is to create and populate some basic tables.

One is a list of all integers between -N and N, another is a list of dates 5 years in the past through 10 years in the future (a scheduled job can continue creating these as needed, going forward) and the last is a list of all hours throughout the day. For example, the inetgers:

```
create table numbers (n integer primary key);
insert into numbers values (0);
insert into numbers select n+1 from numbers; commit;
insert into numbers select n+2 from numbers; commit;
insert into numbers select n+4 from numbers; commit;
insert into numbers select n+8 from numbers; commit;
insert into numbers select n+16 from numbers; commit;
insert into numbers select n+32 from numbers; commit;
insert into numbers select n+64 from numbers; commit;
insert into numbers select n+128 from numbers; commit;
insert into numbers select n+256 from numbers; commit;
insert into numbers select n+512 from numbers; commit;
insert into numbers select n+1024 from numbers; commit;
insert into numbers select n+2048 from numbers; commit;
insert into numbers select n+4096 from numbers; commit;
insert into numbers select n+8192 from numbers; commit;
insert into numbers select -n from numbers where n > 0; commit;
```

This is for DB2/z which has automatic transaction start which is why it seems to have naked commits.

Yes, it takes up a (minimal) space but it makes queries *much* easier to write, simply by selecting values from those tables. It's also very portable across pretty much *any* SQL-based DBMS.

Your particular query would then be a simple:

```
select n from numbers where n >=3 and n <= 10;
```

The hour figures and date ranges are quite useful for the sort of reporting applications we work on. It allows us to create zero entries for those hours of the day (or dates) which don't have any real data so that, instead of (where there's no data on the second of the month):

```
Date       | Quantity
-----------+---------
2009-01-01 |        7
2009-01-03 |       27
2009-01-04 |        6
```

we can instead get:

```
Date       | Quantity
-----------+---------
2009-01-01 |        7
2009-01-02 |        0
2009-01-03 |       27
2009-01-04 |        6
```

Answer (score 4):

```
SQL> var N_BEGIN number
SQL> var N_END number
SQL> exec :N_BEGIN := 3; :N_END := 10

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>  select :N_BEGIN + level - 1 n
  2     from dual
  3  connect by level <= :N_END - :N_BEGIN + 1
  4  /

         N
----------
         3
         4
         5
         6
         7
         8
         9
        10

8 rows selected.
```

This uses the same trick as Tony's. Note that when you are using SQL*Plus 9, you have to make this query an inline view as Tony showed you. In SQL*Plus 10 or higher, the above is sufficient.

Regards,
Rob.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the MODEL clause for this.

```
SELECT c1 from dual
  MODEL DIMENSION BY (1 as rn)  MEASURES (1 as c1)
  RULES ITERATE (7)
  (c1[ITERATION_NUMBER]=ITERATION_NUMBER+7)
```

Answer (score 4):

One way to generate numbers from range is to use `XMLTABLE('start to end')`:

```
SELECT TO_NUMBER(column_value)  integer_value
FROM XMLTABLE('3 to 10');
```

I added TO_NUMBER because COLUMN_VALUE is a string

**[DBFiddle Demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=62d2b4104a68a87c6f458a53f950ee80)**

Comment: That's a clever little trick, and much easier to understand that the others

Answer (score 3):

this single line query will help you,

```
select level lvl from dual where level<:upperbound and 

                              level >:lowerbound connect by level<:limt
```

For your case:

```
select level lvl from dual where level<10 and level >3 connect by level<11
```

let me know if any clarification.

Answer (score 1):

Or you can use Between

```
Select Column1 from dummy_table where Column2 Between 3 and 10
```

Answer (score 1):

Gary, to show the result that he explained, the model query will be:

SELECT c1 
FROM DUAL
MODEL DIMENSION BY (1 as rn)
MEASURES (1 as c1)
RULES ITERATE (8)
(c1[ITERATION_NUMBER]=ITERATION_NUMBER+3)
ORDER BY rn

;)

I always use:

SELECT (LEVEL - 1) + 3 as result
FROM Dual
CONNECT BY Level <= 8

Where 3 is the start number and 8 is the number of "iterations".

Answer (score 1):

This is a late addition. But the solution seems to be more elegant and easier to use.

It uses a pipelined function that has to be installed once:

```
CREATE TYPE number_row_type AS OBJECT 
(
  num NUMBER
);

CREATE TYPE number_set_type AS TABLE OF number_row_type;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION number_range(p_start IN PLS_INTEGER, p_end IN PLS_INTEGER)
    RETURN number_set_type
    PIPELINED
IS
    out_rec number_row_type := number_row_type(NULL);

BEGIN
  FOR i IN p_start .. p_end LOOP
    out_rec.num := i;
    pipe row(out_rec);
  END LOOP;

END number_range;
/
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
select * from table(number_range(1, 10));

NUM
---
  1
  2
  3
  4
  5
  6
  7
  8
  9
 10
```

The solution is Oracle specific.

Comment: Hi @Codo. yes, I can. But, the result is the same :(

Answer (score 0):

I just did a table valued function to do this in SQL server, if anyone is interested, this works flawlessly.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[NumbersBetween]
(
    @StartN int,
    @EndN int
)
RETURNS 
@NumberList table
(
    Number int
)

AS

BEGIN

WHILE @StartN <= @EndN
    BEGIN
    insert into @NumberList
    VALUES (@StartN)
    set @StartN = @StartN + 1
    END

Return

END
GO
```

If you run the query: "select * from dbo.NumbersBetween(1,5)" (w/o the quotes of course) the result will be

```
Number
-------
1
2
3
4
5
```

Answer (score 0):

I want to share an usefull query that converts a string of comma and '-' separated list of numbers into a the equivalent expanded list of numbers:

An example that converts '1,2,3,50-60' into

```
1
2
3
50
51
...
60
```

```
select distinct * from (SELECT (LEVEL - 1) + mini as result FROM (select REGEXP_SUBSTR (value, '[^-]+', 1, 1)mini ,nvl(REGEXP_SUBSTR (value, '[^-]+', 1, 2),0) maxi from (select REGEXP_SUBSTR (value, '[^,]+', 1, level) as value from (select '1,2,3,50-60' value from dual) connect by level <= length(regexp_replace(value,'[^,]*'))+1)) CONNECT BY Level <= (maxi-mini+1)) order by 1 asc;
```

You may use it as a view and parametrize the '1,2,3,50-60' string

Answer (score 0):

```
create table numbers (value number);

declare
    x number;
begin
    for x in 7 .. 25
    loop
        insert into numbers values (x);
    end loop;
end;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answers already provided, it is possible to combine the listagg function with connect by to obtain the result in the format mentioned in the question. See a code example below:

```
SELECT 
   DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR(LISTAGG(S.INTEGERS,',' ) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY S.INTEGERS), 300,1) RESULT 
FROM 
   (SELECT 
      INTEGERS 
   FROM 
      ( SELECT ROWNUM INTEGERS FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 10) 
   WHERE 
      INTEGERS >= 3 
   ) S;
```

OutPut:

```
SQL> 
RESULT
----------------
3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
```