# Converting date range to multiple period

Tags: sql, oracle, informatica-powercenter

I have table like below

```
ID StartDate    EndDate
1  15-MAR-2009  8-DEC-2011
2  14-JAN-2010  18-FEB-2013
```

I need output something like this -

```
ID  StartDate    EndDate
1   15-MAR-2009  31-DEC-2009
1   1-JAN-2010   31-DEC-2010
1   1-JAN-2011   8-Dec-2011
2   14-JAN-2010  31-DEC-2010
2   1-JAN-2011   31-DEC-2011
2   1-JAN-2012   31-DEC-2012
2   1-JAN-2013   18-FEB-2013
```

I have 9i oracle as database, I would perfer to do this with informatica but seems difficult to find solution there, cant create a procedure so need sql query. If anyone can provide in informatica 8.6 then that would be even great.

Edited :-

```
Create table test_range
(Sr_No number,
start_date date,
end_date date)

create table yr_range
(years date);
```

Insert statements :-

```
insert into test_range values (1,'15-MAR-2009','8-DEC-2011');
insert into test_range values (2,'14-JAN-2010','18-FEB-2013');

insert into yr_range values ('31-Dec-2005');
insert into yr_range values ('31-Dec-2006');
insert into yr_range values ('31-Dec-2007');
insert into yr_range values ('31-Dec-2008');
insert into yr_range values ('31-Dec-2009');
insert into yr_range values ('31-Dec-2010');
insert into yr_range values ('31-Dec-2011');
insert into yr_range values ('31-Dec-2012');
insert into yr_range values ('31-Dec-2013');
```

As suggested in one of the answer, I have created another table to get desired output, is it possible using one table only(i.e. test_range)? I m want exploer all the options before finalizing the one.

Comment: I don't get the relationship between existing data & your suggested output.

Comment: I think, OP is breaking the date range per year i.e. one row is broken in multiple rows, each row containing one year period only.

Comment: As yogendra mentioned 31st Dec is year end date so I need to break one row to multiple rows based on that and enddate whichever is lesser in that year

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you had something like a years dimension, where each row represented a year, then you would join with it based on whether the year falls within the range.  This will give you the number of rows you need, and then for each row you conditionally output the start/end ranges.  This should also handle cases where your range is less than a year and thus would not be split up.

y.Year is assumed to be an integer.

See working example here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d4589/13/11

```
Create table test_range
(Sr_No number,
StartDate date,
EndDate date);

create table yr_range
(years number);

insert into test_range values (1,'15-MAR-2009','8-DEC-2011');
insert into test_range values (2,'14-JAN-2010','18-FEB-2013');

insert into yr_range values ('2005');
insert into yr_range values ('2006');
insert into yr_range values ('2007');
insert into yr_range values ('2008');
insert into yr_range values ('2009');
insert into yr_range values ('2010');
insert into yr_range values ('2011');
insert into yr_range values ('2012');
insert into yr_range values ('2013');


select
r.Sr_No,
CASE
  When to_char( r.StartDate, 'yyyy') = y.years Then r.StartDate
  Else to_date( y.years || '/01/01', 'yyyy/mm/dd')  
END as StartDate,
CASE
  When to_char( r.EndDate , 'yyyy') = y.years Then r.EndDate
  Else to_date( y.years || '/12/31', 'yyyy/mm/dd')  
END as EndDate 
from test_range r, yr_range y 
where
      to_char( r.StartDate, 'yyyy') <= y.years  
  AND to_char( r.EndDate, 'yyyy')  >= y.years;
```

You could also generate your years sequence using some of these techniques:
[ORACLE SQL:Get all integers between two numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1453747/oracle-sqlget-all-integers-between-two-numbers)

Comment: I have edited the questions and I m able to get desired out with few changes - heres the query - select
sr_no,
CASE
  When (Start_Date < y.years and to_char(y.Years,'yyyy')=to_char(Start_Date,'yyyy') )Then Start_Date
  Else to_date(to_char(y.Years,'yyyy') || '/01/01', 'yyyy/mm/dd')
END as StartDate,
CASE
  When End_Date > y.years Then to_date(to_char(y.Years,'yyyy') || '/12/31', 'yyyy/mm/dd')
  Else End_Date
END as EndDate
from test_range r,yr_range y
where 
r.start_date <= y.Years
and to_number(to_char(r.End_Date,'yyyy')) >= to_number(to_char(y.years,'yyyy'))

Comment: I was thinking y.Year would be an integer, not date.  You run into a problem with `Start_Date < y.years`. Consider when Start_Date is 12/31/2009, then `12/31/2009 < 12/31/2009` is false, so you get a start date of 01/01/2009, which is almost a whole year earlier than the real start date.

Comment: Try going back to something more like to_char(r.StartDate,'yyyy') = y.Year in the CASE When part.

Comment: thanks for pointing out 12/31/**** start date problem with query. It works fine now, I think using similar appoarch we can code in informatica also.

Comment: small doubt "to_char( r.StartDate, 'yyyy') <= y.years" in this line, do we need to convert year to number again aftr applying to_char?

Comment: It works as long as both are a 4 digit years(not something strange like the year 800) since it is doing an alphabetic comparison.   It probably would be better to wrap it in a to_numeric though, maybe more efficient.  You can test a integer string comparison like `where '2005' <= 2005` and see it comes back true and `where '2006' < 2005` comes back false as you would expect.  It is doing a string comparison as if both were strings, and alphabetically 2005 is before 2006 so it actually works.  I didn't it that way on purpose, I had thought about to_numeric but forgot to add it.