# ORACLE SQL equivalent of generate_series from Postgresql

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to migrate some code from a postgresql db to an Oracle db.
There is a portion of the code that uses generate_series() which is exclusive to postgres.

```
SELECT 
     ITEM
     generate_series(1, ITEM.QTY:: INTEGER ) as TABLE_ID
FROM TABLE
```

This creates duplicate records for each ITEM based on the ITEM.QTY value.
If the ITEM has a qty of 4 then it will return 4 rows for that ITEM each with a different TABLE_ID of 1, 2 ,3 , and 4.

For example, if the original data looks like this:

| ITEM | ITEM.QTY |
| --- | --- |
| item1 | 4 |

The select statement with generate_series will return:

| ITEM | ITEM.QTY |
| --- | --- |
| item1 | 1 |
| item1 | 2 |
| item1 | 3 |
| item1 | 4 |

What would be the ORACLE SQL equivalent way of doing this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ORACLE SQL:Get all integers between two numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1453747/oracle-sqlget-all-integers-between-two-numbers). Or for new range per some ID: [Generating dates between two dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16207543/generating-dates-between-two-dates)

Comment: i think the idea behind your link is similar to what @ahmed did

Comment: Of course, but this is a goal: do not answer the same questions again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try the following:

```
SELECT T.ITEM, C.RN itemQty 
FROM tbl T JOIN
(
 SELECT  ROWNUM AS RN
 FROM dual
 CONNECT BY 
 ROWNUM <= (Select MAX(itemQty) From tbl)
) C
ON T.ITEMQTY >= C.RN
ORDER BY T.ITEM, C.RN
```

You may also use a recursive query as the following:

```
WITH CTE(item,itemQty, qty) AS
(
  SELECT item, itemQty, 1 FROM tbl
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT item,itemQty, qty+1 
  FROM CTE
  WHERE qty+1 <= itemQty
)
SELECT ITEM, QTY FROM CTE
ORDER BY ITEM, QTY
```

See a [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/LwwtGGtz).

Comment: Is there a way to create the ID based on ITEM so that it restarts at 1 for each new ITEM? Using your demo, I added an item2 with qty 3 and the ITEMQTY number increments to 5 instead of ending at at 4 for item1 and then creating 3 new rows for item2. I am assuming 

https://dbfiddle.uk/g96wjE3J

Comment: Yes,  I'll update the answer

Comment: Tried implementing the first solution but the max(itemqty) from my database is 31000 so i stopped it after it ran for 2+ hours. I tried it with a fixed value instead of max(itemqty) so i know it works. When I try the CTE solution, I get ORA-00942 (the table does not exist) , ORA-02063 (preceding line from <db_name>) , and ORA-02063 (preceding 2 lines from <db-link>). Do you have any suggestions on what else to try? The table I am pulling from has about 250k ITEMS and the max(itemQty) is 31000 so doing that many joins using the first solution doesnt seem feasible.

Comment: Roughly speaking,  let us say that the average of itemqty is 15k, then the returned rows will be(250K items * 15k)  which is too much (3750M). Maybe performing [pagination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/241622/paging-with-oracle) on the outer query will help.